# Drawing numbers from a set, quantile

Tags: probability, distributions, combinatorics

We have a set containing $20$ numbers from $1$ to $20$. Each time we draw only one number, and repeat it $15$ times (without replacement). Let's denote $X-$ the largest drawn number. Find the smallest ${{16} \choose {15}}/{20 \choose 15}$-fractile  of a random variable $X$.

So, we look for such $x_p$ that $F(x_p)\geq {{16} \choose {15}}/{20 \choose 15}.$ If $X$ is maximum of all drawn numbers, then $F_X(t)=\Bbb P(X\leq t)=\Bbb P(X_1\leq t, ...,X_m\leq t)$ and, if all of $X_1,...X_m$ are iid then we have $\Bbb P(X_1\leq t)\cdot...\cdot\Bbb P(X_m\leq t)$. But... how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $15 \le X \le 20$.  You have:

- $\mathbb P(X\le 15) = \dfrac{{15 \choose 15}}{{20 \choose 15}}$
- $\mathbb P(X\le 16) = \dfrac{{16 \choose 15}}{{20 \choose 15}}$
- $\mathbb P(X\le 17) = \dfrac{{17 \choose 15}}{{20 \choose 15}}$

So, depending on your precise definition of the "${{16} \choose {15}}/{20 \choose 15}$-fractile  of a random variable $X$", a reasonable answer might be $16$.

An alternative might be to say $\mathbb P(X\le 16) = {{16 \choose 15}}/{{20 \choose 15}}$ and $\mathbb P(X\ge 17) = 1-{{16 \choose 15}}/{{20 \choose 15}}$, implying that both $16$ and $17$ and any value between them could be said to be the ${{16} \choose {15}}/{20 \choose 15}$-fractile